find a specific row of matrix multiplication with this definition
Given the definition of matrix multiplication, i want to determine what a particular row of the matrix multiplication $AB$ is. To define matrix multiplication itself, the book follows this following definition:

Consider the linear system:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n&=b_1\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n&=b_2\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n&=b_m
\end{align}
$$
If we represent the system with matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_m
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
x_1\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots\\a_{m1}\end{bmatrix}+
x_2\begin{bmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\\\vdots\\a_{m2}\end{bmatrix}+
\cdots+
x_n\begin{bmatrix}a_{1n}\\a_{2n}\\\vdots\\a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_m\end{bmatrix}
$$
then when we let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots&a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix},\quad
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix},\quad
b=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_m\end{bmatrix}
$$
we must define matrix equation $Ax=b$ as
$$
Ax=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots&a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}
=x_1\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots\\a_{m1}\end{bmatrix}+
x_2\begin{bmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\\\vdots\\a_{m2}\end{bmatrix}+
\cdots+
x_n\begin{bmatrix}a_{1n}\\a_{2n}\\\vdots\\a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}=
b
$$
From the definition $Ax$, we now define matrix product $AB$ in which $B$ can have more than one column. First, we suppose the associativity was satisfied:
$$A(Bx)=(AB)x$$
If column vectors of $B$ are $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$,
$$
Bx=\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=
x_1b_1+x_2b_2+\cdots+x_nb_n
$$
and hence, using linearity property,
$$
A(Bx)=A(x_1b_1+x_2b_2+\cdots+x_nb_n)=x_1(Ab_1)+x_2(Ab_2)+\cdots+x_n(Ab_n)
$$
we get
$$
(AB)x=A(Bx)=x_1(Ab_1)+x_2(Ab_2)+\cdots+x_n(Ab_n)
$$
So, using the definition "$Ax$" above, the column vectors of $AB$ should be
$$
Ab_1,Ab_2,\cdots,Ab_n
$$

A brief excerpt from the book 'Contemporary Linear Algebra' by Howard Anton and Robert C. Busby.
With this definition of $AB$, we can easily find a specific column of $AB$ because
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix}Ab_1&Ab_2&\cdots&Ab_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is, $c_j(AB)=Ac_j(B)$.
But how to find a specific row of $AB$? To represent the $AB$ with the matrix like
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix}a_1B\\a_2B\\\vdots\\a_nB\end{bmatrix}
$$
should we go back to the first lienar system that appear at the beginning of this question? That is, should we now define $xA=b$ instead of $Ax=b$?
First of all, since the definition of matrix multiplication so far is quite cumbersome, I am curious about a way to find a specific row using only the definitions given so far (and a few additional definitions).

If you allow the use of $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ then it should be clear. Otherwise, a very, very good question.

We can use transpose as @Sean Roberson pointed out.
When the column vectors of $B$ are $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$, we know that
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix}Ab_1&Ab_2&\cdots&Ab_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then we can get the transpose of the $AB$ using the difinition above. If we suppose that the row vectors of $A$ are $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$:
$$
(AB)^T=B^TA^T=\begin{bmatrix}
B^Ta_1^T&B^Ta_2^T&\cdots&B^Ta_m^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, if we transpose $(AB)^T$ again, we get
$$
((AB)^T)^T=AB=
\begin{bmatrix}
B^Ta_1^T&B^Ta_2^T&\cdots&B^Ta_m^T
\end{bmatrix}^T
=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1B\\a_2B\\\vdots\\a_mB
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, the i-th row vector of $AB$ is the $a_iB$. In other words,
$$
r_i(AB)=r_i(A)B
$$

Let $A = (a^i_{\ \ j})$ and $B = (b^k_{\ \ l})$ where $A$ is a $m \times n$ and $B$ is a $n \times r$. The $i$-th row of $A$ is $(a^i_{\ \ 1} \cdots a^i_{\ \ n})$ and the $j$-th column of $B$ is of the form $(b^1_{ \ \ j} \cdots b^n_{ \ \ j})^T$. Therefore we have that, $(AB)^i_{ \ \ j} = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} a^i_{ \ \ k}b^k_{ \ \ j}$. From here it also follows that the $i$-th row of $AB$ is,
$$\sum_{1 \leq j \leq r} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} a^i_{ \ \ k}b^k_{ \ \ j}$$
You can use the notation above to express the $i$-th row of $AB$ as $(a^i_{ \ \ k} b^k_{ \ \ 1} \cdots a^i_{ \ \ k}b^k_{ \ \ j} \cdots a^i_{ \ \ k} b^k_{ \ \ r})$ where we use the Einstein approach to mask the summation i.e,
$$\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} a^i_{ \ \ k}b^k_{ \ \ j} : = a^i_{ \ \ k}b^k_{ \ \ j}$$
Here are some good notes - https://web.mit.edu/course/3/3.11/www/modules/index.pdf.
